# Pegar selectedIndex do combobox e passar para input?

Tags: javascript

No exemplo a seguir pego o valor da descrição no alert; preciso pegar esse texto da caixa suspensa no value de um campo input... como adaptar isso? tenho que enviar essa descrição via post! obs: não quero enviar o value do combobox e sim o valor selectedIndex, espero que tenham entendido.

```
    <script>  
    function desc(){  
    var i = document.form2.cb.selectedIndex;  
    alert(document.form2.cb[i].text);  
    }  
    </script>  

    <form name="form2">  
    <select name="cb" onchange="desc()">  
    <option value="1">VERDE</option>  
    <option value="2">AMARELO</option>  
    <option value="3">AZUL</option>  
    <option value="3">BRANCO</option> 
    </select>  
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode preencher um campo oculto:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cbi">
```

```
function desc(){  
    var i = document.form2.cb.selectedIndex;  
    document.form2.cbi.value = document.form2.cb.selectedIndex;
}
```